# python-rocksdb installation -llz4 missing inside /usr/bin/ld

Tags: python-3.x, rocksdb

With the installation of python-rocksdb on ubuntu i had the following issue of missing packages:

[image]

Then i run:

```
apt-get install build-essential libsnappy-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libgflags-dev
```

allmost all sorted, the only one that i can't find is -llz4. Anyone know what is the pacakge that i need to install?

At the moment whenever i run

pip install python-rocksdb

i always received the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted!

```
sudo apt-get install liblz4-dev
```